# Natural language parsing, practical example

Tags: java, nlp

I am looking to use a natural language parsing library for a simple chat bot.  I can get the Parts of Speech tags, but I always wonder.  What do you do with the POS.  If I know the parts of the speech, what then?

I guess it would help with the responses.  But what data structures and architecture could I use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A part-of-speech tagger assigns labels to the words in the input text. For example, the popular Penn Treebank tagset has some 40 labels, such as "plural noun", "comparative adjective", "past tense verb", etc. The tagger also resolves some ambiguity. For example, many English word forms can be either nouns or verbs, but in the context of other words, their part of speech is unambiguous.
So, having annotated your text with POS tags you can answer questions like: how many nouns do I have?, how many sentences do not contain a verb?, etc.

For a chatbot, you obviously need much more than that. You need to figure out the subjects and objects in the text, and which verb (predicate) they attach to; you need to resolve anaphors (which individual does a *he* or *she* point to), what is the scope of negation and quantifiers (e.g. *every*, *more than 3*), etc.

Ideally, you need to map you input text into some logical representation (such as first-order logic), which would let you bring in reasoning to determine if two sentences are equivalent in meaning, or in an entailment relationship, etc.

While a POS-tagger would map the sentence

```
Mary likes no man who owns a cat.
```

to such a structure

```
Mary/NNP likes/VBZ no/DT man/NN who/WP owns/VBZ a/DT cat/NN ./.
```

you would rather need something like this:

```
SubClassOf(
   ObjectIntersectionOf(
      Class(:man)
      ObjectSomeValuesFrom(
         ObjectProperty(:own)
         Class(:cat)
      )
   )
   ObjectComplementOf(
      ObjectSomeValuesFrom(
         ObjectInverseOf(ObjectProperty(:like))
         ObjectOneOf(
            NamedIndividual(:Mary)
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Of course, while POS-taggers get precision and recall values close to 100%, more complex automatic processing will perform much worse.

A good Java library for NLP is [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/). It doesn't, however, go much beyond POS-tagging, chunking, and named entity recognition.

Comment: "you would rather need something like this:"

In your post, what syntax is that and what are you describing.

Comment: This is OWL 2 (see: http://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/Syntax). OWL is a fragment of first-order logic. In the context of this answer it's just an example of a format that one could convert natural language sentences into, to get automatic reasoning capability in return.

Comment: Between a POS tagger and the logical extract of a sentence, there is an intermediate step of a parser, for example a chart parser, which does the chunking of the POS tagged words. And then to extract the logical form, we need to determine argument dependencies. And later some logic processing.

Answer (score 5):

Natural language processing is wide and deep, with roots going back at least to the 60s. You could start reading up on [computational linguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_linguistics) in general, [natural language generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_generation), [generative grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_grammar), [Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chains), [chatterbots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatterbot) and so forth.

Wikipedia has a [short list of libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing_toolkits) which I assume you might have seen. Java doesn't have a long tradition in NLP, though I haven't looked at the Stanford libraries.

I doubt you'll get very impressive results without diving fairly deeply into linguistics and grammar. Not everybody's favourite school subject (or so I've heard reported -- loved'em meself!).

Answer (score 3):

I'll skip a lot many details and keep this simple. Parts of Speech tagging help you to create an [parse tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) out of a sentence. Once you have this, you try to make out a meaning as unambiguously as possible. The result of this parsing step will greatly aid you to frame a suitable response for you chatterbot.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have part of speech tags you can extract, for example, all nouns, so you know roughly what things or objects someone is talking about.

To give you an example:

Someone says "*you can open a new window.*" When you have the POS tags you know they are not talking about a *can* (as in *container*, *jar* etc., which would even make sense in the context of *open*), but a *window*. You'll also know that *open* is a verb.

With this information, your chat bot can generate a much better reply that will have nothing to do with *can openers* etc.

Note: You don't need a parser to get POS tags. A simple POS tagger is enough. A parser will give you even more information (e.g. what is the subject, what the object of the sentence?)